# JQuery hover of form <li> to cause array string to appear

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, insert, hover

I want to develop a humorous multiple choice quiz that behaves as follows: When the user mousesover each of the multiple choice responses (in the left column) a comment will appear in the right column.

The html looks like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <li>
         <strong>Question two:</strong>
         <ol>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="Q2A" id="Q2A" value="Response 2a">Response 2a</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="Q2B" id="Q2B" value="Response 2b">Response 2b</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="Q2C" id="Q2C" value="Response 2c">Response 2c</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="Q2D" id="Q2D" value="Response 2d">Response 2d</label></li>
         </ol>
      </li>
      </ol>
      </form>
      <div id="column2">
         <h3 id="upComment"></h3>
      </div>
      <script src="_scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
      <script type='text/javascript' src='_scripts/fquiz.js'></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript/jquery I’ve come up with so far looks like this. You can see what I’m trying to accomplish, but it doesn’t work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //an array of comments
    var comments = [
        "comment 1",
        "comment 2",
        "comment 3",
        "comment 4",
        "comment 5",
        "comment 6",
        "comment 7",
        "comment 8",
    ]
    //this line creates an array out of the <li>s 
    $("li").each(function () {
        $(this).hover(function () {
            //this next is supposed to get an item from the comments array and append it to the upComment id in the second column (but it doesn’t)
            $(comments).each.appendTo(“#upComment”);
        });
    });
    //alternate non-functioning code:
    /*  $("li").hover(function(index) {
$.each(comments, function(index) {
$(this).insertAfter("#upcomment");
});
});     */
}); //end document ready
```

Comment: You have eight comments, and four `<li>` elements below 'Question 2,' should the first four comments show up (one comment beside each 'response') on hovering the `<li>`, or a random comment from the eight? Incidentally, you say that we "*can see what I’m trying to accomplish*" - broken code tells us nothing about the problem you're trying to solve; *explain* what you're trying to do, then there's fewer questions and complexities; make it *easy* for us, and help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I am just starting out learning jQuery & JavaScript. I will remember not to include broken code, but try to explain exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: No, no: please: *include the broken code*, that shows what you've tried; but it's not a substitute for clearly explaining what you intended for it to do. My apologies, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('label').hover(function() {
    $('#' + this.children[0].value + 'Comment').css('opacity','1');
  }, function() {
    $('#' + this.children[0].value + 'Comment').css('opacity','0');
  }

);
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.comment {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="1a" />&nbsp;Answer 1a</label>
    </td>
    <td id="1aComment" class="comment">Comment for 1a.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="1b" />&nbsp;Answer 1b</label>
    </td>
    <td id="1bComment" class="comment">Comment for 1b.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="1c" />&nbsp;Answer 1c</label>
    </td>
    <td id="1cComment" class="comment">Comment for 1c.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="1" value="1d" />&nbsp;Answer 1d</label>
    </td>
    <td id="1dComment" class="comment">Comment for 1d.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I realize that there are many ways to solve a problem like this. Turning it into a table is an elegant solution. Thank you. It works beautifully. I would like, however, a way to make the comment appear in a different <div>. I gave the div and id of "column2", and had it appear in a <h3> with an id of "upComment."

Comment: Thank you. I figured out how to put the comments into a separate ,<div>. Not that difficult!